# Como mostrar datos de varios modelos en vista Detalles usando ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Saludos, tengo una duda respecto a como enviar o mostrar los datos de una tabla que tiene relación con otra, en este caso una tabla Areas contiene un id de departamento al que pertenece, pero necesito mostrar en la vista el nombre del departamento no el Id, como puedo hacer esto? Se que sonará muy básico pero necesito ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Miguel cual es el error? El que esta en la imagen o que la consulta no te esta retornando lo que buscas?

Comment: En este caso ambas, pero en concreto es que no me devuelve el dato que necesito que vendria siendo el Nombre del departamento

Comment: Buenas.Hay muchas formas de resolverlo. Se deberia resolver con las propiedades de navegacion. Si me das mas detalle te ayudo hacerlo. Si podes mostra las tablas. Saludos

Comment: Hola Miguel, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para ver el funcionamiento básico del sitio (y conseguir tu primera medalla), y que leas [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus preguntas. Por ejemplo, sería ideal que pusieras el código como texto en lugar de como una imagen, además, también ayudaría que indicaras por qué está la línea subrayada en rojo (¿qué error te da el IDE?)

Answer (score 1):

Miguel, solo te faltan unos detalles. El problema está en la forma en que funciona LINQ con el fin de optimizar los tiempos de carga a la hora de realizar una petición a la BD. Pongamos un ejemplo

En tu método Index tienes una consulta (Supongamos que utilizas LINQ) que te muestra todas las areas.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var areas = db.Areas;
        return View(areas.ToList());
    }
```

en este caso asumes que necesitas solo los datos de la tabla Area tal y como se encuentran representados en tu BD Nombre_Area y Departamento_Id que se almacena como un entero. Si lo que necesitas es mostrar información de otra tabla involucrada como en tu caso Departamento deberias hacer uso de "Include" con el fin de especificar que necesitas tambien la carga de otra tabla para mostrar sus datos. Por lo que tu metodo Index queda de esta forma:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var areas = db.Areas.Include(a => a.Departamento);
        return View(areas.ToList());
    }
```

de esta forma en tu vista puedes llamar lo siguiente:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Departamento.Nombre)
</td>
```

espero te sea de ayuda